# VBA: Chart_Data points not visible in graph

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I dont get the line curve for the data given below however I see the data being plotted but not visible as a smooth line. Please help.

```
      Column B  Column C
          x      y

        0.00      0.00
       -0.10    0.29
       -0.35    0.48
       -0.65    0.48
       -0.90    0.29
       -1.00    0.00

         
      Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
      ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
     ch.Activate

     p=1
For i = 1 To 6
           
        ser_count = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        p = ser_count + 1

         ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        
       
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("b" & i)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("c" & i)

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Format.Line.Weight = 1
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid

 Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim objCh As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart
Dim Srs As Series

Set objCh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
'Set objCh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set ch = objCh.Chart
With ch
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    
     Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Srs
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("b1").Resize(6)
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("c1").Resize(6)

        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Format.Line.Weight = 1
        .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Its visible,  i am animating it , so one data point at  a time , i want the loop going, Lee

Comment: @MathInquiry, Glad your problem was solved. Make the chart type a distributed type with markers, and use dovents and time delays in the loop to see the animation effect.

Comment: the below code is not working for dynamic data, Please help

Comment: Srs.XValues = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(47, 3 * j - 1)).Resize(i + 1)
  Srs.Values = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(47, 3 * j)).Resize(i + 1)

Comment: I have another post on resize, please suggest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170959/vba-chart-resize-dynamic-data-for-chart-not-working