# VBA_Chart_ Resize dynamic data for chart_Not working

Tags: excel, vba, resize, excel-charts

Resize is not working for dynamic data.Resize is not working for dynamic data.
Please help

```
Dim objCh As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart
Dim Srs As Series

Set objCh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
Set ch = objCh.Chart

ch.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
Set Srs = ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
For j = 1 To 5
   For i = 1 To 5

      Srs.XValues = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3 * j - 1)).Resize(i + 1)
      Srs.Values = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3 * j)).Resize(i + 1)
   Next i
Next j
```

Comment: I would say `Resize` always works correctly... Can you explain (in words) what are you expecting from your code to do?

Comment: Hi, please look at my another post of same type:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167500/vba-chart-data-points-not-visible-in-graph

Comment: replace my "B1" and "C1" with Cells(1, 3 * j - 1) and Cells(1, 3 * j) resp.  Resize(i + 1) works but the Cells(1, 3 * j - 1) is not .

Comment: I do not have time for puzzle details. If you are able to replace whatever you need and answer my questions I can try helping you. Otherwise, I am a busy man and I do not have time to look for your previous questions, sorry...

Comment: sorry, i just want to replace my "B1" and "C1" with Cells(1, 3 * j - 1) and Cells(1, 3 * j) resp. Resize(i + 1) works but the Cells(1, 3 * j - 1) is not picking the data.

Comment: Am i missing anything?

Comment: Only to answer my question, even if it is in the first comment... I cannot understand what you try doing in your code.

Comment: I have many x, y columns . I am using the loop to plot all the x,y data in the same graph.  Is my  syntax  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3 * j - 1)).Resize(i + 1) correct ? ..Hope this helps

Comment: `Resize` enlarges the range. I mean `Range("A1").Resize(1)` means the same "A1" range. `Range("A1").Resize(2)` means `$A$1:$A$2`. That's why I do not understand what you are trying to do. You maybe are confusing `Resize` with `Offset`...

Comment: I fixed it !! Thanks for taking your time to help!

Comment: How did you do it? Since you asked about help, it is good to tell us where the problem was...

Comment: Hi, for chart , while using cells inside the range like  Range(Cells(1, 3 * j - 1)) it does'nt accept , instead use  Range(Cells(1, 3 * j - 1),Cells(1, 3 * j - 1))